# Windows Forms Remove Close Button

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a Windows Forms app and I'm wanting to remove the close button from the top. I'm aware of the `ControlBox` option, but I'm wanting to provide a help button.  Is there a way to have the Close button not visible while maintaining the help button?

Comment: Why would you be so mean to your users?  What if they want to close the form?

Comment: It will be a time clock for our shop employees....I don't want them to be able to close the software...

Comment: @Servy then they right click the taskbar and choose "Close"? what if he has his own custom close button to handle some event OnClose that isn't easily supported elsewhere? I'm not sure this is really a question of morality ...

Comment: @Sam I ask because there's almost always a better approach.  The OP's answer has only confirmed that for me.  As to your example, there's a `FormClosing` event for a reason.

Comment: @Sam the machine this will run on will only serve one purpose.  The taskbar won't be visible and there will be no mouse/keyboard to open it.  I'll be providing a 7"(ish) touchscreen and a badge reader.

Comment: @Servy If there is a better approach I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @Jared Removing the `close` button won't stop them from closing the program, it will only make it slightly more work.  You should be either making your program a `Service` so that it can't be closed by a regular user, or have it running on some other machine (server) entirely.  You can then have an form/UI program that just displays data from that service/external program that really can be closed.

Comment: @Servy The backend of the program IS on our server.  The user interface however won't be.  While I could simply swallow (so to speak) the `FormClosing` event I'd rather not mess with that.  The screen that the user will have access to will do nothing more then have this app open all the time.  Taskbar display is hidden with the  `ShowInTaskbar` option.  With the way I have this set I see very few options to close the program (and quite frankly if they don't want to get paid....).  So is it possible to hide the close button yet leave the help button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet may be to subcribe to the FormClosing event of the form like so and cancel the closing action:

```
// In your code somewhere subscribe to this event
Form1.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;

void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

The benefit of doing this is that it prevents the user from closing the application from the close button and the taskbar.

Obviously you don't want to ALWAYS cancel the form from closing.  So you will want to set some type of boolean flag that you will check in the event listener as to whether you want the form to be allowed to close or not.  Example:

```
void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (BlockClosing)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

**EDIT:**  If you don't want to approach the problem that way, and you really do intend to completely remove the close button, then your best bet is to create your own custom title bar.  In that case, you set the form's FormBorderStyle property to None.  And you then dock your custom title bar to the top of the form.  Here is some sample code from one I made a while back:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Spectrum.UI
{
    public partial class TitleBar : UserControl
    {
        public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event EventHandler MinButtonClick;
        public event EventHandler MaxButtonClick;
        public event EventHandler CloseButtonClick;

        #region Properties
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public string Title
        {
            get { return TitleLabel.Text; }
            set { TitleLabel.Text = value; }
        }

        [Category("Appearance")]
        public bool MinimizeEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return minButton.Visible;
            }
            set
            {
                minButton.Visible = value;
            }
        }

        [Category("Appearance")]
        public bool MaximizeEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return maxButton.Visible;
            }
            set
            {
                maxButton.Visible = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public TitleBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ShowTitleBarImage = false;
        }

        #region Mouse Events
        private void TitleBar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnMouseDown(e);
        }

        private void TitleBar_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnMouseUp(e);
        }

        private void TitleBar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnMouseMove(e);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Button Click Events
        private void minButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MinButtonClick != null)
                this.MinButtonClick.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        private void maxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MaxButtonClick != null) 
                this.MaxButtonClick.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CloseButtonClick != null) 
                this.CloseButtonClick.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

[image: This is how my custom titlebar looked when I was done]

As you can see from the image, I also added a background image to the control.  Depending on your patience and your requirements, you can use images and PictureBox controls to make this look as much like a standard title bar as you need.

In the above example I placed three buttons on the control with images I found online to represent minimize, maximize, and close.  in your case you would simply exclude a close button.  I also placed a string on the control with an appropriate font to serve as the title of the window.

Adding the custom title bar to your form is easy.

```
public TitleBar titleBar = new TitleBar();
titleBar.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
titleBar.MaximizeEnabled = true;
titleBar.MinimizeEnabled = true;
titleBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10, 40); // Width doesn't matter - I wanted it 40 pixels tall
titleBar.Title = "Title Example";
titleBar.MinButtonClick += titleBar_MinButtonClick;
titleBar.Max ButtonClick += titleBar_MaxButtonClick;
this.Controls.Add(this.TitleBar);
```

And then last step is to set up your event listeners for the min and max button clicks:

```
private void titleBar_MinButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}

private void titleBar_MaxButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

You may also note that I included events for mouse down, up and move in my title bar.  This was so that I could create listeners in my form to move the form when the user clicked and dragged the title bar.  This is optional and depends on if you need the user to be able to move your application window.

The added benefit of doing this is that can use the title bar for additional controls.  For example, my application was custom written for use on a toughbook style tablet computer with a small touchscreen display.  In my application, utilization of the limited space was extremely important.  I was able to further modify what I've described here to also include menu bar style control directly on the title bar.  In addition, I added more buttons to the left of the stand minimize, maximize, and close buttons.  Really helped me utilize every square inch of the screen in my application.  Couldn't have done it with the standard title bar.

Comment: I'm wanting to remove the button all together.

Comment: Okay.  Well it may seem a little odd but in the past when I have wanted to remove the close button altogehter, I set my form's FormBorderStyle property to None.  This removes the title bar entirely.  And then I made my own custom title bar for the top of the application.  Not hard to do.  It's essentially just a panel that you dock to the top of the form with a label for the title of the form.  And if you wish to maintain a minimize and maximize button, you can very easily mimic their functions with two buttons and callbacks.

Comment: I actually will probably end up doing this.  If you will change your answer to this and elaborate with details I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Added some code to get you started.  It's very basic and you may need to add additional methods/properties to make it as much like a standard titlebar as you want it to be.

Comment: I didn't need the code per se...just wanted something there in case someone else stumbles across this.

Comment: do u have a sample project of this windows form design design

Answer (score 5):

Can you simply use `Form.ControlBox = false` (or via the designer as you point out rather negatively in your comment) and then **add a custom help button on the form**?

**EDIT**: A colleague of mine wrote an Excel add in and had a requirement to remove the `X` from certain forms (e.g. a Progress Bar that shouldn't be closed). He found a [function written by Stephen Bullen](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Excel/Default.htm) that did just that. I've only seen this function used in VB, but perhaps you can get some ideas or direction out of his approach of using Windows API to solve your issue.

Comment: +1, I have even seen people add a false bar, and then they handle the different events.

Comment: This does the EXACT same thing as the `ControlBox` option in the visual designer.  Your just doing it in code.

Comment: @Jared The point of my answer was not to show you how to use ControlBox in code vs in the visual designer, it was to bring to your attention the **idea** of using `ControlBox` (whether it's via code or designer, it does not matter) to get rid of the close box rather than disable it, like you want, then add your **own** custom help button physically on the form.

Comment: The only reason I said that comment the way I did was because the response showed that you didn't read the question.  I mention that property explicitly. I'm sorry if I sounded short/negative, but it just was something that I directly mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @Jared The response shows that I read the qeustion and gave you a different approach to solving it with what you already knew. Hence, the second half of my answer. The whole idea to my answer was for you to use `ControlBox` (like you **already** were) and **THEN** add a **CUSTOM** help button on your form, since you literally can't make the **X** invisible without building the form from scratch. The only way to accomplish an invisible X with a help button is by using the aforementioned approach. I apologize for our miscommunication, as clearly it was half my fault as well ;-)

Comment: @Sam My bad then I misread what you were saying.  (I just get frustrated at the masses assuming that a person has no clue why they are doing what they are doing.  I've given you an upvote to correct your rep.)  Anyway, I have considered this, but was wanting to use the real-estate up top for that button if possible.  Again, I'm sorry about misreading your answer and the ensuing comments.

Comment: @Jared No hard feelings, understood. P.S. I updated my answer with a link to some pretty interesting stuff. It's not a direct answer, but it might help guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

This code will disable the Close button. I am not sure if you can actually make it invisible. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20379/Disabling-Close-Button-on-Forms

```
//
// source code 
// Code Snippet
 private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;
 protected override CreateParams CreateParams
 {
     get
     {
        CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
        myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON ;
        return myCp;
     }
 }
```

Good luck!

Comment: You can't. It's build into the API

Comment: @ColeJohnson While you may not be able to "Disable" the button you can catch the close event and just discard it.  I've done this before.  I'd just assume remove the confusion of providing the button though

Comment: It breaks expected UX functionality to catch the close event and ignore it. You should disable it

Comment: @ColeJohnson in all honesty I'm really hoping to have the button not visible all together.  My original question is simply if the `Close` button can be hidden while maintaining the `Help` button.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the close button, but disable it. AFAIK you can't remove it without writing your own window control. But don't do that and break UX

Comment: I disagree about the fact that it shouldn't be removed.  It cleans up the UI and shouldn't EVER be used by the user.  I'm aware that this shouldn't "normally" be done, but this will be a Time Clock on a machine that is dedicated for it's use.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `this.ControlBox = false`.